# Mongoid Map Reduce with has_one

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

I am using Mongoid and MongoDB in an application I am making.  I have a user that has one profile like so:

```
class User

 field :email, :type => String
 field :name, :type => String
 field :date_of_birth, :type => DateTime
 has_one :profile

end

class Profile

 field :votes, :type => Hash
 field :biography, :type => String
 belongs_to :profile

end
```

The votes hash is structured like so:

```
profile : {
  "user_id" : ObjectId("511b76b0e80c505750000031"),
  "votes": {
    "vote_count": 3,
    "up_votes": 3,
    "down_votes": 0
  }
}
```

I am running map reduce like so:

```
map = "
  function () {
    values = {
      name: this.name
    }
    emit(this._id, values);
  }
"

reduce = "
  function (key, emits) {
    return emits;
  }
"

User.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(replace: "leaderboards").each do |document|
  ap document
end
```

This works fine and creates a new collection in Mongo called leaderboards.  However I am trying to map some data from the profile so it includes the vote_count field from the profile.

Essentially making my map function look like so:

```
map = "
  function () {
    values = {
      name: this.name,
      votes: this.profile.votes.vote_count
    }
    emit(this._id, values);
  }
"
```

However I am have difficulty grabbing the profile associated with the user.  Does anyone know how I can pull the data from the users profile?

If something isn't clear here let me know.  Any help would be appreciated.

Tony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way in MongoDB to do "joins" of data from different collections on the server side - you have to do them in your client application, or, better, consider [document embedding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/#data-modeling-decisions), especially as there is a 1:1 relationship between your user and profile collections.

Now, if design change isn't an option, you could perform two mapReduce() in sequence:

1. the one you have on User, but using the user_id as key, and add the name
   as a field
2. a mapReduce on Profile with the same user_id key and the
   vote_count, specifying a [merge output](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#output-to-a-collection-with-an-action) into your leaderboards
   collection

Does this help?

regards

Ronald